# AUCTeX indenting after \newcommand

Tags: indentation, auctex

If I use a command that begin a new block (according to `AUCTeX`), e.g.:

```
\newcommand\Test{\begin{abstract}}
```

And then I start my document:

```
\begin{document}
```

AUCTeX will indent my code as if I typed:

```
\begin{abstract}
  \begin{document}
```

Is there a way to tell AUCTeX to **not** consider command in `newcommand` for indentation?

*Note: It may looks silly to declare a new command for `\begin{abstract}` but my real code is not about such command (simplified for the example). Actually the problem occurred while using the `algorithm` packages, and I wanted to define a new command such as `IfAny` (`\newcommand\IfAny[1]{\If{\textbf{any} #1}`) which does not really involved an environment.*

Full example code after <kbd>C-x h</kbd> <kbd>M-x indent-region</kbd>:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\Test{\begin{abstract}}

  \begin{document}
\end{document}
```

---

The exact command concerns the `algorithm` and `algpseudocode` packages:

```
\newcommand\IfAny[1]{\If{\textbf{any }#1}}
```

Use like:

```
\IfAny{}
  \State ...
\EndIf
```

Which cannot be made into an environment (`\newenvironment`) unfortunately.

Comment: I've added a full example for reconstruction. It also shows the effect.

Comment: The indentation error could be avoided by adding `\newcommand\dummy{\end{abstract}}`. A real solution would require a re-write of `LaTeX-indent-calculate`. Your`\newcommand` could be more complicated, e.g., span multiple lines. One needs a stack with indentation tokens such as a `{` symbols and begin-environment macros to match the begin and end-tokens. the begin-tokens push, the end-tokens pop. `{`-tokens have higher priority, i.e., if a `}` is read but an environment-token is on the stack the environment tokens are popped until an `}` is found and also popped. pop/push corresponds to indents

Comment: A moderator deleted my not-quite-answer. The OP made a comment to that answer which I think should be visible to others, so I copy it here: “Actually the problem occurred while using the algorithm packages, and I wanted to define a new command such as `IfAny` (`\newcommand\IfAny[1]{\If{\textbf{any} #1}` ) which does not really involved an environment.”

Comment: And to the above, my comment: If `\If` results in an indentation, I'm surprised. Perhaps *that* is the problem that needs addressing?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I have updated my question. I have configured AUCTeX to indent `\If`, `\For`, etc. But the problem is here even without configuration and with `\begin{abstract}` (and it is why I did not put the real command in the question at first since it does not work without a bit of configuration... ).

Comment: And more generally, TeX/LaTeX is such a flexible language, allowing all kinds of constructs that really clash with basic usage, that designing really robust automatic indentation support is a near impossible task. You'll either have to work around problems as they pop up due to bending the rules, or give up on using automated indentation altogether.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I was thinking that there could be a way to configure AUCTeX to "reset" indentation after a `\newcommand` to fix this problem, but I am really new to AUCTeX and not really used to `elisp`...

Comment: Your code gives me unbalanced parentheses. Furthermore `\If` is undefined. About your comment: `\newcommand` can occur within `\newcommand` and within the body of the document. So your "reset" would break indentation. I go with Harald's comment (+1).

Comment: You could fake it in a manner analogous to what @Tobias suggested above, or my deleted post: Just replace `\end{abstract}` by whatever cancels the indentation triggered by `\If`. You can also place this code between `\iffalse` and `\fi` (often my own preferred method).

Comment: @Tobias Sorry there was a missing brackets. `\If` is defined by the `algpseudocode` package (updated my question). By "reset" I meant as it was before the `\newcommand`, not to 0.

Comment: What might have been nice, perhaps, is a pair of magic comments causing AUCTeX to not apply its indentation rules to stuff between them. Perhaps that's a reasonable feature request for the AUCTeX team?

Comment: Hi, I am looking for some hints onAUC-TeX intendation within style files.  Thats why I stumbled upon your question.  I was wondering, why one would create such code in a LaTeX file.  A) you normally would define `\newcommand`s in the preamble and not in the document.  B) Why would you define a command, that inserts half of the environment, when you are using Emacs, which could easily insert the full environment in one command?  Also C) why would one want to define such a macro, it is also broken in terms of clean LaTeX code?  Or did I misunderstood your question?

Comment: @Jan I putting `\newcommand` in the preamble, see the snippet. As explained at the end of the question, the problem also occurs with `\IfAny` command which is not related to an environment (as far as I know).